# How to escape at sign (@) in TFS test case?

Tags: tfs

I'm adding steps to a TFS test case and I want to add the literal text: `@example.com` for one of the test steps. However, TFS 2015 parses `@example` as a parameter. How can I escape the at sign (@) so that I can include `@example.com` literally instead of as a parameter?

Comment: Looks like if the character right before `@` is not a white-space, it is not considered a parameter. However, it's just a personal observation, I failed to find the evidence in the docs. My TFS is 2018.2 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems we cannot escape the symbol "`@`" smoothly.

The symbol "`@`" is used for creating or adding a parameter in Test case steps. Please see [Add parameters to a test case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/repeat-test-with-different-data?view=vsts#add-parameters-to-a-test-case) for details.

I have submitted a [user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/35371348-escape-the-parameters-with-symbol-in-test-case) to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future release...

For now as a workaround you can try below ways to escape the parameters :

- As @YanSklyarenko mentioned,  if the character right before `@` is
  not a white-space, it is not considered a parameter. (e.g.:
  `test@example.com`)
- Type white-space or any other special characters behind `@`, (e.g.:
  `@ example.com`, `@'example.com`)

Comment: I feared that was the case. Now I know the situation and workarounds, and thanks for creating the feature request. In addition to what you stated, it also seems some punctuation characters before the @ get treated similarly to whitespace.